# Tables with multicolumn lines

Tags: tables, multicolumn, rules

I'm trying to format a table with many columns such that the empty cells on each row have a continuous, coloured line through them.
I've tried adapting a `multicolumn` command with a `rule` command in it, but it doesn't always yield what I'm looking for.
My table is also extending past the margin despite specifying `\textwidth` in the `tabular*` environment.

I don't fully understand the syntax of multicolumn and of `tabular` and `extracolsep` so any insight would be appreciated.

Please find below my code. The first two tables are trial runs. The second does not work as expected as lines in rows 1 and 2 were supposed to show.
The third table extends past the margin and doesn't use `multicolumn`.
The fourth uses `multicolumn` but the `rule` lines are formatted poorly.

Am I missing any relevant packages?

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Working (though some parameters are unclear to me)}
\begin{tabular}{ p{3cm} p{3cm} p{3cm} }
  \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}}  & 3 \\
  4 & \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}} \\
   7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Not working (lines in rows 1 and 2 not showing; very small)}
\begin{tabular}{ p{3cm} p{3cm} p{3cm} }
  \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}}  & 3 \\
  4 & \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 0cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}} & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Extending past margin (original code to be adpated using multicolumn)}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\centering}p{1.5mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5mm}>{\raggedright}p{4mm}>{\raggedright}p{4mm}>{\centering}p{2mm}}
\hline
\noalign{\vskip2mm}
\multirow{1}{1.5mm}{{\footnotesize{}$m$}} & \multicolumn{15}{l}{{\footnotesize{}text}} & \tabularnewline[2mm]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip2mm}
{\footnotesize{}1} & \textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.5ex]{166mm}{2pt}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}text1 }\tabularnewline
{\footnotesize{}2} & \textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.5ex]{153mm}{2pt}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & {\footnotesize{}text2} & {\footnotesize{}text3} & \textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.5ex]{3mm}{2pt}}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Lines of wrong length; poor formatting; extends past margin if adding more text}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\centering}p{1.5mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{3mm}>{\raggedright}p{2mm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5mm}>{\raggedright}p{4mm}>{\raggedright}p{4mm}>{\centering}p{2mm}}
\hline
\noalign{\vskip2mm}
\multirow{1}{1.5mm}{{\footnotesize{}$m$}} & \multicolumn{15}{l}{{\footnotesize{}text}} & \tabularnewline[2mm]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip2mm}
{\footnotesize{}1} & \multicolumn{30}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.2em]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}}}\hfill\mbox{}} & {\footnotesize{}text1 }\tabularnewline
{\footnotesize{}2} & \multicolumn{28}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.2em]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}}}\hfill\mbox{}}   & {\footnotesize{}text2} & {\footnotesize{}text3} & \multicolumn{1}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[0.2em]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}}}\hfill\mbox{}}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.